# Javascript, txt-file "scraping", can't figure how to find whole words instead of parts of em

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this coding assignment where I am supposed to extract rules for a game from txt-file. Problems is that I can't figure out how to pick only exact numbers instead of parts of em (eg. "11" can be found in "211", and that's not what I want). I have read that regEx is the answer, but I haven't been able to implement it in my code. I'm open for using regEx, but also if there is some other way around (eg. lodash) I would like to hear it.

```
Rules are ordered like this:


1. First chapter name
 100. first subrule.
 101. second
 102. third

2. same thing with second chapter
 200. first subrule.
 201. second
 202. third
 ...
```

my code looking like this:

```
const filterChapters = () => {
const filtered: Chapter[] = [];
let index = 1;

const alreadyExists = (chapterIndex:Number):Boolean => {
  const exists = filtered.some( chapter => chapter.index === chapterIndex);
  return exists;
}

while(true) {
  const indexStr = index + '. ';
  const regExp = new RegExp("\b"+ indexStr +"\b")
  const ruleIndex = data.indexOf(regExp);
  
  if (ruleIndex) {
    const endOf = data.substring(indexStr).indexOf('\n');
    const name = data.slice(ruleIndex, endOf);
    console.log(name);
    
    if (alreadyExists(index)) {
      setRules({ chapters: filtered})
      break;
    } else {
      filtered.push({ index, name })
      index++;
    }
  } else {
    setRules({ chapters: filtered});
    break;
  }
}
```

I want output to be something like this:

```
    const rules = {
  chapters: [
    { index: 1, text: 'first chapter' or '1. first chapter' },
    { index: 2, text: 'same thing with second chapter' or '2. same thing with second chapter' },
  ]
}

then I would like to include subrules on chapter objects like this: 

{ index: 1, 
text: 'first chapter' or '1. first chapter' 
subrules: [
  {index: 100, text: 'first subrule.'},
  {index: 101, text: 'second'},
  {index: 102, text: 'third'}
]
},
```

Thanks for your time, and you may also point out other mistakes in my code if you think something seems odd or illogical.

Comment: Can you explain what you hope your output to be?

Comment: Yes ofcourse! I edited it to my question

Answer (score 0):

#### The advice to use regex is good, and you should follow it

As it is a coding exercise, we should not do it for you, because it will destroy your learning. Read about regex online and update your question with your attempts.

#### Here are some hints

Step 1. Split the input into an array of separate lines. For example, you can use the Javascript `.split("\n")` function.

Step 2. Split each line of text into the number part, the ". ", and the remaining text. A regex that might do this is

```
([0-9]+)\. (.*)
```

The parentheses will "capture" the two parts for you. You can test this at [www.regexr.com](http://www.regexr.com). Click the `Details` tab and click on each line of text in turn, seeing what has been captured in each of the two capture groups.

[image: Demonstration of capture]

Step 3. Check each result in turn. Decide if it is of the form "n" or "nnn", and handle it accordingly.

Remember to mark the answer as correct if it helps you appropriately for your educational needs. 8-)

Comment: Thanks! I agree that it would be counter productive to give a whole answer when it's about learning.